# Login to Intuit Qucikbooks with Python requests

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, quickbooks

I am trying to pass the authorization of Quickbooks.

I am using a code:

```
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
login_data = dict(Email=username, Password=password)
login_url = 'https://c35.qbo.intuit.com/app/clients'

def main():
    with requests.session() as session:
        response = session.post(login_url,
            data=login_data,
            headers={
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'
                })
```

I am getting a page with a bunch of "Preload" javascript code and can't get to the app's real homepage.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use selenium and login through that

Comment: Great! Upvote comment if it helped :-)